# SQL Transaction not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, transactions

I am using below SQL to delete records and insert into Customers table inside a transaction. If there is an error in the insert statements, I am seeing the error message and when I try to execute `select * from customers`, it is not displaying result set. And when I close SSMS window, it is showing `There are uncommitted transactions. Do you wish to commit these transactions before closing the window?`

After I click OK, results are getting displayed from the table. So, is there any locking mechanism taking place while using transaction.

```
USE CMSDB;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN t1;

        DELETE FROM Customers
        print @@trancount -->prints 3 since there are three records
        INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS
        INSERT INTO CUSTOMERd --> error here
        INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS

    COMMIT TRAN t1;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    print 'hi' --> not printing
    select @@trancount --> not resulting anything
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
        ROLLBACK TRAN t1;
    -- Error Message
    DECLARE @Err nvarchar(1000)
    SET @Err = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    RAISERROR (@Err,16,1)
END CATCH
GO
```

Message

```
(3 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid object name 'dbo.Customerd'.
```

Comment: Sounds like at some point (before running this last batch) you highlighted only code with `BEGIN TRANSACTION;`. What does `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;` say?

Comment: Seems it is not entering catch for some reason. I tried to print @@trancount in catch but couldn't.

Comment: Just `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;` on its own. Again, I think at some point you performed at least one `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` without either committing it or rolling it back.

Comment: Yeah, I remember I did BEGIN TRAN without rollback. After that I committed the transaction through the prompt message and I was able to retrieve the records. And just select @@trancount is also not giving any result set.

Comment: What do you mean "not giving any result set"? Is it acting like it's blocked too (the status window says "Executing query...")? Or do you mean it returns a ZERO? Please be explicit and remember that we can't see your screen.

Comment: I am sorry. It is not printing anything nor able to get any result out of the select/print @@trancount. I have updated the resultant message.

Comment: YOu need to look in books online at the limitations of what try catch will find or not find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpt from [TRY…CATCH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) description:

> The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when
>   they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY…CATCH construct:
>
> - Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from    running.
> - Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as    **object name resolution errors** that occur after compilation because of 
>     deferred name resolution.

In this case what happens is

> The error is not caught and control passes out of the TRY…CATCH
>   construct to the next higher level.